# Use prescalor to determine the period of a clock cycle in microcontrollers (AVR)

Tags: assembly, timer, counter, microcontroller, avr

I'm quite new to AVR and microcontroller programming. I don't quite understand some concepts in Timer/Counter. I found this problem when reading today:

> Generate an active high 1 KHz digital waveform with 30 percent duty cycle from the OC1A (PB1) pin. Use the polling method to check the success of the output compare operation. The frequency of the clock is 16 MHz.

The solution given is this:

> Solution: Setting the prescaler to 8, then the period of the clock signal to the TCNT will be 0.5 usec. The numbers of clock cycles that the signal is high and low are 600 and 1400, respectively.

I don't really understand why setting the prescalar to 8 would make the period of the clock signal 0.5 usec? Can someone please explain the math here to me? Then, with that in mind, why would the number of clock cycles be 600 and 1400? Where do those numbers come from?

I think me not understanding the solution has something to do with not understanding the exact concept of prescaler. My understanding is that say the clock frequency is 16 MHz, if the prescaler is 8, then the output frequency would be 2 MHz. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. A prescalar of 8 on 16MHz reduces the frequency to 2MHz. each tick will be 1/2,000,000 of a second or 0.5 us.

The question asks for 1kHz cycle, on 30% and off for 70%. 1/1kHz is 1 ms or 1000 us or 2000 ticks. 30% of that is 600 ticks, and the remaining 70% is 1400 ticks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This might be a silly question, but what's a tick? Why would 1000 us be equal to 2000 ticks? Thanks!

Comment: A clock tick is the time it takes for the clock to increment TCNT register by one. With the prescalar, a tick takes 1/2 of a microsecond. So 1000 microseconds takes 2000 ticks.